# Nesting Folders in Windows 7 for a Media Center

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, tuner-card

I have built a DVR comp using 2x 3TB HD's and and want my tuner card to be able to record movies and tv as long as I have space on either one of them, unfortunately Win 7 forced me to partition one of the drives so I currently have 3 save areas.  I can read from but all 3 spaces already, I was wondering if there was a way to set them up so the program which wants to record in "Username\TV Recordings" sees the space of all three drive areas and records to whichever has the available space?